# error: Developer Error in Google login in release mode

Tags: react-native

I have implemented GoogleLogin which is working in debug mode, But in release it is not working and throw an error "Developer Error", I don't understand that what is the issue
and also having some queries about firebase.
1). If i have created an app with XYZ package id then can i create second app with that package id XYZ in firebase(firebase opened with different gmail account)?
2). If i have created an app in firebase with XYZ id then what we should do to create app with that created package id(XYZ)?
Should i delete old app ?
OR
I can't create app with a package id which is either deleted or not?

Comment: Hello guys, I want to share the solution here, may it help you in future.
Issue solved with adding sha1 key for release in firebase